# Compare first value in array with others

Tags: javascript

What is the recommended way to compare if the first value in array is higher or lower than other values.

I have an array as in below

var a = [8,3, 114,34,0,2]

I want to compare if value a[0] is higher or lower than  other array values via js.
EDIT: Expected var a result : 8 is lesser , since there are higher values than 8 in array.

Ex 2: var b = [34 , 2, 23, 8]
expected output: higher since all other numbers are lower than a[0]

Comment: Use `for` loop to iterate over values. Then `if` to compare with the other items.

Comment: Agree to @zerkms , as you can't have time complexity less than N , as you need to go through each value at least once to compare.

Comment: Could it not be higher than some values and lower than others and equal to yet others? Or do you mean whether it is higher or lower than all of them. For example, would the output you want be higher, lower, lower, higher, higher?

Comment: Agreed.  I think this question would be easier to answer if we had an example of what a desired return value would look like.

Comment: This question is not clear at all , what happens on this case [34,34,0,10 ] ? also on your Ex 2. are you referring to the first array ? a[0] or b[0] ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if it is higher than all other values or lower than all other values you can call min and max function like the following

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, a);
   var max = Math.max.apply(null, a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be a forloop starting in 1.

```
for(i = 1; i < a.length;i++){
    if(a[0] > a[i])
    {
       //do something
    }
    else if(a[0] < a[i])
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: @DawnPatrol If he follows your advice he will be trying to access an array element that doesn't exist, namely a[a.length]. There is no problem with this solution. He starts at i=1 because he doesn't need to compare the first element against itself.

Answer (score 1):

Testing for strict equality as well...

```
var a = [8,3, 114,34,0,2];

a.forEach(function(element) {   
   element === a[0] ? console.log (element + ' is equal to ' + a[0]) :
   element > a[0] ? console.log(element + ' is higher than ' + a[0]) :
   console.log(element + " is lower than " + a[0]); 
});

//"8 is equal to 8"
//"3 is lower than 8"
//"114 is higher than 8"
//"34 is higher than 8"
//"0 is lower than 8"
//"2 is lower than 8"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Create an array of -1/0/+1 for each value relative to first elt.
const comps = ([head, ...tail]) => tail.map(e => e < head ? -1 : e === head ? 0 : +1);

// Define some little convenience routines.
const greater = c => c === +1;
const less    = c => c === -1;

// See if some or all element(s) are greater or less.
const someGreater = a => comps(a).some(greater);
const someLess    = a => comps(a).some(less);
const allGreater  = a => comps(a).every(greater);
const allLess     = a => comps(a).every(less);

// Test.
const input = [8,3, 114,34,0,2];

console.log("Some are greater", someGreater(input));
console.log("Some are less", someLess(input));
console.log("All are greater", allGreater(input));
console.log("All are less", allLess(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

A funny trick :

```
function first_is_bigger (array) {
  var comp = array.join(" && " + array[0] + " > ");
  return Function("return 1 | " + comp + ";")();
}
```

```
first_is_bigger([0, 1, 2]) // false
first_is_bigger([0, -1, -2]) // true
```

Explanation :

```
array = [1, 2, 3];
```

```
comp = array.join(" && " + array[0] + " > ");
// comp = "1 && 1 > 2 && 1 > 3"
exec_comp = Function("return " + comp + ";");
// exec_comp = function () { return 1 && 1 > 2 && 1 > 3; }
exec_comp()
// false
```

Problem : `0 && anything` is always `false` :

```
array = [0, -1, -2]
```

```
comp = array.join(" && " + array[0] + " > ");
// comp = "0 && 0 > -1 && 0 > -2"
exec_comp = Function("return " + comp + ";");
// exec_comp = function () { return 0 && 0 > -1 && 0 > -2; }
exec_comp()
// false :-(
```

Fix : `1 | anything` is always different than `0` :

```
exec_comp = Function("return 1 | " + comp + ";");
// exec_comp = function () { return 1 | 0 && 0 > -1 && 0 > -2; }
exec_comp()
// true :-)
```

> Warning : improper use of dynamic evaluation opens up your code for injection attacks :-(

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of the question, we intend to check whether a given element is the maximum value of the array (the first one in our specific case). I have implemented a more general `function`, where you can check this for any element, but where the `index` 0 is the default.

```
function isHigher(input, index) {
    if (index === undefined) {
        index = 0;
    }
    for (var i in input) {
        if ((i !== index) && (input[i] > input[index])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Call `isHigher(a)` to check whether the 0'th element is the biggest. If you want to check this for the fifth element, call `isHigher(a, 5)`